# unexpected Memory Usage in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: gnome, 16.04, ram

I am a long time Mint user, was using cinnamon for the past 3years, I have installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 today in my new machine, the memory usage of gnome is shocking, it uses 1.2 gigs of RAM with no applications opened. Any of you faced similar problem ? is there any workaround ?

Thanks in advance

[image: screen shot attached]

Answer (score 2):

Chances are your new machine has more ram (probably a lot more ram) than your old machine. Linux will utilize ram for disk caching and other functions when applications aren't using it. The more ram you have the more Linux can use behind the scenes. For more info see [Don't Panic](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)

Comment: @tomsk This Q&A is about Ubuntu 16.04. Secondly the answer here quotes a source. Do you have a source to quote? Thirdly there is a rule to be nice here.

Comment: I quite dont understand, I was talking about Ubuntu 16.04, what source to quote? I said that your link Dont Panic is "wrong" because Ubuntu 14 uses disk cache into RAM too and it has much higher usage. So it is not only about disk cache, it means that something is wrong in Ubuntu 16.04 or in kernel.

Answer (score 1):

If you think this is a problem and it could be related to processes you can use

```
top -o %MEM
```

to check this. top is sorting process by % of memory usage then.
use command "free" to check what is used.
I guess most of the memory is used for buffering.

Answer (score 1):

There is a confirmed serious memory leak in Ubuntu 16.04 and still present in 16.04.1, hopefully it will be fixed in 2nd point release. I have also been waiting for the fix since 16.04's release in April, it's not really usable for me until it gets fixed.

Now i'm having thoughts in converting to Debian 8.6 because of this and it's already 7 months and yet no fix.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1572801.